# regex pick up "-" next to a number but not next to a letter

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/czmlFD/6

please take a look at the regex I currently have. I want everything to remain the same except I don't want it to pick up the `-` in `non-gaap` and `value-added` but it must still pick up the other negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

`(?<!\S)[\$\(]{0,2}[-\d][\d,.]*\)?%?`

The negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` will assert that the regex must not come after a letter, which will eliminate the hyphenated strings from your matches.

Additionally, the change at the start from `\$?\(?` to `[\$\(]{0,2}` will mean that the left bracket in `($2,605)` will now be included in that match, whilst also only ever allowing up to two dollar signs and left brackets to sit next to each other.

Finally, the change from `0-9` to `\d` in your sets will save you two characters.

All other matches remain in place.

This can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/DYaCTB/1)**.

Comment: wow. sweet. Thanks. i didn't even catch the error in `($2,605)`

Comment: oh, oh, got a problem if the `-` is the first character... check it out... https://regex101.com/r/BVYaqz/3